# Does the order you declare your class variables affect how memory will be allocated?

Tags: c#, clr

I came across the following, an excerpt from the book

> C# 6.0 in a Nutshell by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari (O’Reilly).
>
> Copyright 2016 Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari, 978-1-491-92706-9.

[image]

I do not see it mentioned there, but would it not follow, then, as a rule of thumb - that **you should always declare the variables in your type in descending order of size**, in order **to avoid the memory waste** being pointed out ?

I mean, if I got it right, we should all be normally taking that into consideration when designing our types.

---

Update:

I came up with the snippet below to prove whether the above is right or wrong. I was expecting S2's size to be different, however (to support what the book says).

```
public struct S1
{
    public byte b;
    public long l;
}

public struct S2
{
    public long l;
    public byte b;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 9)]
public struct S3
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte b;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public long l;
}

S1 s1 = new S1();
S2 s2 = new S2();
S3 s3 = new S3();

Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s1)); //prints 16
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s2)); //prints 16
Console.WriteLine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(s3)); //prints 9
```

Comment: "in your type in descending order of size" Not quite. From packing point of view, `short, short, int, long` is as good as `long, int, short, short`. Keep in mind that optimizing data to take less memory may have significant impact on performance.

Comment: @AlexD: Thanks for adding your bit. Can you elaborate on how being concerned with not wasting memory and following the guideline above would lead to significant impact on performance ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure CPUs don't like dealing with data smaller than the word size so whilst you may save space, performance will suffer

Comment: So (you two), from your point of view - what is the significance of such behavior/knowledge ?

Comment: @Veverke It depends on hardware. Roughly, when you read just one byte from memory, some bytes around are read/cached as well. So if you have `byte x, byte y` and access them one after another, it might be significantly faster than in case of `byte x, long, long, long, byte y`. But it is a separate topic :).

Comment: Thanks for that. Feel free to make answers out of your comments so I can give you something in return :)

Comment: Rules of thumb: 1) avoid struct, 2) use LayoutKind.Auto . When dealing with unmanaged code, you don't get to pick the layout anyway.

Comment: @Veverke Oh, it did not deserve to be promoted to answer :-). But thank you anyway! Your observation regarding layout makes sense, but it is rather something to keep in mind and tweak if needed, not a default practice.

Answer (score 3):

The book's excerpt is quite misleading.  It implies that 7 bytes are 'wasted' but that doesn't have anything to do with the order of the fields.  You'd consider swapping the order, putting the `long` member first.  But that doesn't accomplish anything, those 7 bytes are *still* unused.

Layout and size for a struct is calculated so that the long is *still* aligned to 8 in an array.  In other words, the elements of an A[] require alignment as well.  That can only work when the struct is 16 bytes long.  Or in other words, swapping the fields just moves the unused 7 bytes to the end of the struct.

Any struct in C# has an implied [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] attribute.  You would have to use LayoutKind.Explicit to force intentional mis-alignment of a field.  Do beware the cost, misaligned fields can be quite expensive, slowing down reads and writes by as much as x3.  Happens when a field straddles an L1 cache line boundary.  And much, much more if the processor doesn't support misaligned accesses, not much of a problem today with the Itanium out of the picture.  And you lose any atomicity guarantee you get from the CLR spec.  You cannot intentionally misalign a field of a reference type (like string), that ruins the garbage collector.

It gets slightly more interesting if the struct has 3 or more members.  Now you can indeed get ahead by ordering them.  Like a byte, long, int, that would take 20 bytes in that order.  If you re-arrange to byte, int, long than it takes 16 bytes, the int fits in the padding.  If you override with LayoutKind.Auto then the CLR will do this for you.

Comment: Hans, you are specifically talking about structs, but, from what I understand, this behavior is not specific to Structs only. The author claims the same happens in custom types (classes) as well.

Comment: A class always has LayoutKind.Auto by default so already gets the best layout.  Everything else is the same.